# Sensing of a pdf file in a specfic directory and printing the ".pdf" file using Java

Tags: java, file, pdf, netbeans, printing

I am creating a program using Java through Netbeans that can sense a new file inside a specific directory (C:\Users\User\Documents). The file to be sensed should be in ".pdf" file format only. Once the program sensed a new file, it will output that a new file is detected in the specific directory. It should display "new file is detected". After the file detection, java will automatically print the newly detected file to a specific printer. (just one printer will be used). The file to be printed should also be printed with a specific attributes such as the number of copies, type of paper, etc. After printing, java will notify the user that the file has been printed.

I searched everywhere and I just found the skeleton code for printing a pdf. I want to know what to do and what to change on the codes below. I am just new to java programming and I found it difficult to determine what to change and what to add on the program. I studied the basics of java but I really find it difficult:(

```
package printpdf;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Sides;


public class Printpdf {

public static void main(String[] args) {

FileInputStream textStream; 
try { 
    FileInputStream textstream = new FileInputStream("GMA trip.pdf"); 
} catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) { 
} 
        Object textstream = null;
if (textstream == null) { 
        return; 
} 

DocFlavor myFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
        Object texttream = null;

Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(texttream, myFormat, null); 

PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
aset.add(new Copies(5)); 
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
aset.add(Sides.DUPLEX); 

PrintService[] services =
        PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(myFormat, aset);

if (services.length > 0) { 
        DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob(); 
        try { 
                job.print(myDoc, aset); 
        } catch (PrintException pe) {} 
} 
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: This is only if u printer support native print of pdf documents. Not many of them available were few years ago on market (low price segment of printers). Otherwise u should use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html class which will call OS native print dialog

Comment: new FileInputStream("GMA trip.pdf")  this is relative path to file "GMA trip.pdf" (depend from directory from which u application started). Instead build full path to pdf document.

Comment: Thank you :) gonna try that first :)

Comment: I personally prefer to use foxit reader to print pdf files (it is possible to start foxit reader in headerless mode, and it is really detects well pdf document orientation, padding and so on).

Comment: Can foxit reader accept printer properties such as number of pages, grayscale, etc. from a database?

Comment: As i know it is impossible. Just simple print of pdf documents. I think you need first, check if printer u use supports native pdf print. Then make decision either to buy printer that have native pdf print capabilities either you might consider to purchase Java Library that able to convert pdf to PostScript.